# Закрасить половину div

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как закрасить `div` на половину красным цветом?

```html
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid;background:red;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: inset 100px 0 #f00;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```